# Wrapping Lua code in Python on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, shell, lua, wrapper, raspberry-pi3

I am using Raspberry Pi model 3 and run my scripts on Raspbian Jessie.

I am trying to benchmark how much Lua is faster than Python. For this I wrote an in-place quicksort in both Lua and Python and printed execution times. Now, I want to show this physically by turning on a LED while quicksort is executing. I have no problem with Python code, I use simple Python RPi.GPIO module. But apparently the Lua RPi.GPIO module is outdated *(not confirmed, it just gives me "This module can only run on Raspberry Pi" error which makes no sense)*.

So now I am trying to wrap my Lua code in Python/C/Bash so that this wrapper script turns on LED while the quicksort executes in Lua. Is there any way to do that? I know nothing about shells or passing scripts as arguments, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe execute a python script that turns on the LED from Lua?

Something like,

```lua
os.execute("python turn_on_led.py")
```

This could be a performance issue, though.

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea if it will build on the RPi, but [Lunatic Python](https://labix.org/lunatic-python) will allow you to embed a Lua VM into Python, meaning that you can have Python invoke the Lua code and control the hardware.